# Why this is not a palindrome?

Tags: java, palindrome

I'm trying to find largest palindrome from product of 2 3-digit number (100-999). My approach was to check is it a palindrome or not using String. I am getting small values.

```
import acm.program.*;

 public class Palindrom extends ConsoleProgram{

    public void run(){
        int last = 0;
        for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i ++){
            for (int k = 100; k <= 999; k++){
                int p = i*k;
                String str = "" + p;
                if(isPalindorme(p, str)){
                    last = p;

                }
            }
        }
        println(last);
    }

    public boolean isPalindorme(int p, String str){
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length()/2; i++){
            if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length()-1-i)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;    
    }

 }
```

I think that maybe the mistake is at this line:

```
String str = "" + p;
```

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to find the line which is not doing what you expected it to. hint: the largest product is likely to be one of the largest values so you may as well start top down, also you can ignore where i<k or visa versa.

Comment: Anything wrong with `return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().equals(str);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also check that `p > last`.